# Bose-Einstein condensation of interacting bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, bose-einstein-condensate

Consider a bosonic Hamiltonian with two-body interactions

$$H=\sum_{ij}T_{ij\,}b_i^\dagger b_j+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}U_{ij\,}b_i^\dagger b_j^\dagger b_j b_i,$$

assuming $U_{ij}=U_{ji}$. Suppose the system has $N\gg 1$ particles and is at zero temperature. We want to variationally determine the single-particle wave function $\langle i|\psi\rangle$ of the ground state $|\psi\rangle$ of Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC). We shall approximate the many-body state  $|\Psi\rangle$ with exactly $N$ particles by a coherent state, i.e.,

$$|\Psi\rangle\approx e^{-\frac{1}{2}N+\sqrt{N}\psi^\dagger}|0\rangle,\quad \psi^\dagger = \sum_i b_i^\dagger\langle i|\psi\rangle.$$

Now the total number of particles of $|\Psi\rangle$ is Poisson distributed and is strongly peaked at its mean value $N\gg 1$. Let $z_i=\sqrt{N}\langle i|\psi\rangle$ be our variational parameters. Then we have

$$E_0=\langle\Psi|H|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{ij}T_{ij}z_i^*z_j+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} U_{ij} z_i^* z_i z_j^* z_j.$$

By taking the variational derivative, we obtain an eigen-equation

$$\frac{\delta}{\delta z_i^*}\!\left[E_0-\mu\!\left(\sum_i|z_i|^2-N\right)\right]=\sum_j T_{ij}z_j+\left(\sum_{j}U_{ij}|z_j|^2-\mu\right)\!z_i=0,$$

which governs the wave function of the BEC ground state $|\psi\rangle$. This equation resembles the Gross-Pitaevskii equation (or the nonlinear Schrodinger equation). Only the Hartree term of the interaction comes into play. But when we calculate the excitation spectrum, we find there are both the Hartree term and the Fock term. We define

$$ b_i=z_i+\tilde{b}_i,\quad b_i^\dagger=z_i^*+\tilde{b}_i^\dagger.$$

Then $|\Psi\rangle$ is the vacuum of the excitation operators $\tilde{b}_i$, i.e., $\tilde{b}_i|\Psi\rangle=0$. Applying Wick's theorem to the excitation operators $\tilde{b}_i$, we obtain

$$\langle b_i^\dagger b_j^\dagger b_j b_i\rangle=\langle b_i^\dagger b_i\rangle\langle b_j^\dagger b_j\rangle+\langle b_i^\dagger b_j\rangle\langle b_j^\dagger b_i\rangle-z_i^* z_iz_j^* z_j.$$

Here we ignore pairing terms of the excitation operators, i.e., $\langle\tilde{b}_i^\dagger\tilde{b}_j^\dagger\rangle=\langle\tilde{b}_i\tilde{b}_j\rangle=0$. Therefore, at constant BEC parameters $z_i$, the total  energy variation is

$$\delta\langle H\rangle_z=\sum_{ij}\left[T_{ij}+U_{ij}\langle b_j^\dagger b_i\rangle\right]\!\delta\langle\tilde{b}_i^\dagger\tilde{b}_j\rangle+\sum_{ij}U_{ij} \langle b_j^\dagger b_j\rangle\delta\langle \tilde{b}_i^\dagger \tilde{b}_i\rangle,$$

which means that the mean-field Hamiltonian governing the excitations contains both the Hartree term and the Fock term. How do I understand that the ground state and the excitations satisfy different eigen-equations and does this mean that the BEC ground state found by the variational method is in general not stable to excitations?